# The electricity has been going off/ has been off

Tags: word-usage, aspect

For example:

It's 9:00 p.m and at 7 p.m the electricity went off.

Which tense is correct and what is the difference in meaning between these tenses?

The electricity ***has been going off*** for 2 hours.

The electricity ***has been off*** for 2 hours.

Thank you.

Comment: Although I have "flagged" this question to ask if the moderators will migrate it to ELL, they won't necessarily take any notice of my one voice. But if *you* ask for it to be migrated, I'm sure they will act. I think you will find ELL more helpful if you have any further questions.

Comment: And another idiomatic way to say it is, “The power’s been out for 2 hours.”

Comment: There are *many* ways. I'd prefer saying: *"There is no power/electricity for past two hours."*

Comment: That's ungrammatical, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both wordings are correct ways of describing different things.

Normally, "has been going off" would be used with the implication "has been going off and on"—meaning "has been on and off intermittently" during the specified time period. In fact, the full expression, "has been going off and on," is quite a bit more common than the shortened but implied form "has been going off [and on]" as a way of describing multiple interruptions in normal service.

In contrast, "has been off" indicates simply an uninterrupted period of being off: there has been no electricity (in this case) for the past two hours.